# Which version of bootstrap i have to use in grouping inputs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap and hence i am working with the help W3schools.com. Now i am modifying a website that have been already made with bootstrap version 3. I have created another html for testing and verifying my code in bootstrap. In the test html, i have included bootstrap.min.css downloaded from [here](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/#download).

I was trying to do input grouping as in [w3schools tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_form_input_group&stacked=h) and it works in my test html and hence i decided to do it in my official website. But when i included the same code in official website the alignment differs and its not working.

When i look into the css folder of official website, instead of `bootstrap.min.css` it was given that `style.min.css`. I have asked the former developer of the same site and he said that bootstrap used is version3.

I didn't understand what really differ? what is `style.min.css` and `bootstrap.min.css`

Can any one please clarify me?

Comment: Try testing with the the same CDN links used in the w3schools example.

Comment: No it can't be done since official website uses `style.min.css`. I am not authorized to change it

Comment: The only other thing I can suggest is to pretty print both minified style sheets and use a file compare utility.

Comment: print  means? In both files the code are written in a line, its hard to compare. Can you please explain the difference between `style.min.css` and `bootstrap.min.css`. Whether both are bootstrap files?

Comment: The simplest way to _pretty print_ a minified file (css or js) is to use your developer tools.  For example in Chrome, click the sources tab and you will see a **{}** icon that _pretty prints_ the minified file.  Copy the source and paste it into a file compare utility.